# Can I bind an argument value ahead of time when using redux-actions?

Tags: redux, redux-saga, redux-actions

I have an action and a saga.

I want to supply a value to the action instance from inside `actions.js`.

I also want to supply a value to the action instance from inside the saga.

So when the reducer associated with the action is called, it receives two values in the payload.

How can I do this?

**actions.js**

```
import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';
export const myAction = createAction('ACTION_NAME'); // How do I supply payload value "foo" here?
```

**sagas.js**

```
function* mySaga({
    yield put(myAction()); // How do I supply  payload value "bar" here?
}
```

**reducers.js**

```
export default handleActions({ 
  'ACTION_NAME': handleReduce(state, { payload: { foo, bar } }) => 
     { /* foo and bar should be defined */ }) });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an action you can add any payload to it you want. Now you just creating action with bare string and no payload.

`createAction(type, payloadCreator)`

**payloadCreator must be a function, undefined, or null**

`createAction('ACTION_NAME', () => { reuturn {foo: 'bar'}; })`

https://github.com/reduxactions/redux-actions/blob/master/docs/api/createAction.md#createactiontype-payloadcreator-createactiontype-payloadcreator

in sagas put accepts bare object with type (string) and payload too

E.g. `yield put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_RECEIVED', products })`

So if createAction returns object with type and payload, it will be used by sagas too. You can use console.log before yeld to check what your action creator returns.

```
console.log('Action for saga:', myAction());    
yield put(myAction()); // How do I supply  payload value "bar" here?
```

Comment: So the payload added when the action is created gets merged with additional payload supplied later?

Comment: @Ben added more details to main answer

Comment: I'm still a little confused. How can I supply value `'foo'` when I initially create the action `createAction('ACTION_NAME')`? Will something like the following add it to the eventual payload? `createAction('ACTION_NAME', { foo })`?

Comment: no, payloadCreator must be a *function, undefined, or null*

Comment: Okay thank you. So the following should work? `export const myAction = (foo) => createAction(MY_ACTION, (bar) => { foo, bar });`? I can then create the action, passing `foo`, and then pass `bar` in the normal way as payload, and reducers will see both?

Comment: yes, but foo and bar should be defined in the scope or you will get error about it. You can use `{foo: 'bar', second: 'whatever'}`